# Export to exisiting xlsx file in SheetJs error

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, xlsx, sheetjs

I am working with sheetjs ,
I amtrying to debug this problemto export to an exisiting sheetjs

This is the function

```
public exportInExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json('test',json);
```

It shows me an erro in test string

```
Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type worksheet
```

Do anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your look like your json

Comment: I did not understand what you mean?